# Facebook FQL get user status made from an app

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to query user status made from app_id but it doesn't work.

This return nothing:

SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = me() IN app_id = xxxx

Answer (score 0):

The FQL documentation says that the column for the ID of the application responsible for posting a particular status is `source`. With that knowledge it's easy to construct a working query:

```
SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = DESIRED_USER_ID AND source = DESIRED_APP_ID
```

I tested it myself and got the expected results.